# Does AspectJ support modifying the JDK bytecode?

Tags: classloader, aspectj

I want to intercept ClassLoader's loadClass method. In order to show the process of loading class by ClassLoader. But I don't know the working principle of aspectj. It can modify the source code of the JDK?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a debugger and step through the process in order to understand it.

AspectJ can weave aspects into existing class files during compilation (CTW, compile-time weaving) or during class-loading (LTW, load-time weaving).

LTW does not work for JDK classes because those classes are always loaded before the weaving agent. So you have a bootstrapping problem there.

What you can do, however, is to apply CTW to the class files in e.g. `rt.jar` from your JRE/JDK distribution, zip the woven class files into another JAR and replace the original one with it. Then if you start the JVM with `aspectjrt.jar` on the boot classpath, you see the aspects in action. I have done that before and it works. But really, this is not what AspectJ was designed for. But you asked, so I told you. It is a very advanced topic though, and I doubt that it is the road you should take as a complete AspectJ greenhorn - no offense meant.

---

**Update:** Because I have been asked this question so often, I created a little [demo project](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_MavenWeaveJDK) showing how to weave aspects into the JRE/JDK. I still do not think it makes sense to use it under normal circumstances, but what the heck: Why do people climb the Mount Everest? Because it exists. ;-)

Comment: I have created a demo project for JDK weaving. See my updated answer.